# Unable to receive the Published message

Tags: rabbitmq

I've installed local Rabbit MQ Server in my development machine, Created Queue Exchange and Routing Key to receive the message. Below is my receiver code.

```
string MQUrl = "amqp://<userName>:<Password>@10.251.74.64:5672/guest";
ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
conFactory.Uri = MQUrl;
using (var connection = conFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    Console.WriteLine("MQ Connection Created");
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel()) { }
} 

channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "dotnet.build.fanout.exchange", type: ExchangeType.Fanout, durable: true, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
            var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
            Console.WriteLine("Queue Name is " + queueName);
            channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, exchange: "dotnet.build.fanout.exchange", routingKey: "dotnet.build.fanout.queue");

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                Console.WriteLine("The Message is:" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body));
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                     noAck: false,
                     consumer: consumer);
```

I'm publishing the message from Rabbit MQ Web Console. But I'm unable to Print the message in Console. Even the message is not getting acknowledged.

Comment: Could you please post the whole code?

Comment: This is my actual code. I'm publishing the message from Rabbit MQ Web Console. So I don't have the Publisher code. The above code which I mentioned is the receiver code.

Comment: Where is the address, port, username, password, vhost for connecting to rmq?

Comment: I'm using my local instance. string MQUrl = "amqp://<userName>:<Password>@10.251.74.64:5672/guest";
            ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
            conFactory.Uri = MQUrl;
            using (var connection = conFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MQ Connection Created");
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                { } }

Comment: ok, somehow without any code for connecting to it?

Comment: I've updated my comment with the connection strings.

Comment: Ok thx, but should update the question with it next time. I've done it for you now ;) Anyhow, do you have a vhost called `guest` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes my vhost is guest.

Comment: Shouldn't consume go before writing the message to console?

Comment: No as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-dotnet.html, BasicConsume is called after the Received event is excuted.

Comment: I replaced the code var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName; with var queueName = "dotnet.build.fanout.queue" and I can able to receive the message which is published. But I'm curious to know why it's not working when I use channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;